# Exposing USB COM serial devices to Docker Windows container

Tags: windows, docker, serial-port, containers, docker-for-windows

I have a script that I want to run as a container. It depends on a an USB camera to run.

My host is a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise machine. I have tried exposing the COM serial ports of my host through WSL 2 to a Linux container, but exposing COM serial ports through WSL 2 [its currently not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ltxu.png), so my only option is using Windows containers.

I followed the process used in the [Microsoft documentation to expose devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/hardware-devices-in-containers#run-a-container-with-a-device) (Just mirroring the OS and version from my host which would be 20H2, and using the GUID for COM serial ports)

```
docker run --isolation=process --device="class/86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73" mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2
```

The container is created and runs for a couple seconds, but when connected to the CLI it displays [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYEFo.png): container 5245931c246cc8181221354158bf7ddad64eb5099a493354a68a39d94feed6f0 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The requested virtual machine or container operation is not valid in the current state. (0xc0370105)

**Docker information:**

```html
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:56:41 2021
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Any feedback will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A USB **camera** is almost certainly (99.99999%) NOT a USB virtual COM serial device.

Comment: Or try changing the hardware itself to a UVC(USB Video Class) interface instead of USB Serial?

Comment: I get the exact same error when running:

`docker run -it --isolation=process --device="class/86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73" mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2 cmd.exe`

trying to access an Arduino that comes up as a Serial COM